# Exit object method in work

Tags: javascript, oop

I am making some SPA app. When app is running at some point i start one method. Some code in there give me boolean. I would like to stop method when is 'half executed' and that boolean is false. I need something like break for loop, but  that might work with methods. It is possible ?

Thanks for answers.

```
if(el === 'work'){
if(!actions.authentication()){
// That code is in another method. I want break that with some code placed here.    
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Thanks for answers on what question?

Comment: I updated my answer..

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I work with, for me, very nested code. If i can ask, can i use a few times return false in one method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda obvious and you almost answered yourself, but you can use `return` ...

```
if(el === "work") {
    if(actions.authentication() == false) {
        return  
    }
}
```